# Laravel Cache Raw Queries

Tags: php, mysql, caching, laravel, laravel-4

I have a repository with a number of raw queries, for example:

```
DB::select(DB::raw(
             'SELECT stuffFields
              FROM stuffTable
              A NUMBER OF COMPLEX JOINS, ETC'
          ));
```

I would like to cache the results from this query, but I encountered a couple of issues:

1) I cannot do ->remember(60), as the Fluent query is not started with the table() method.

2) I cannot do

```
DB::table('stuffTable')
          ->select(DB::raw(
             'stuffFields
              A NUMBER OF COMPLEX JOINS, ETC'
          ))->get();
```

because there are those joins and the FROM clause is getting appended at the end of the query (after the joins), and this throws an SQL syntax error.

I also cannot bring out the joins in a join() method, as they contain nested queries (is there a way to perform rawJoin()...i couldn't find anything like that?).

Can anyone suggest a way to either restructure the Fluent calls or a common way to cache such raw queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on @justrohu answer you could have a method you wrap all of your raw queries around...

```
public function cacheQuery($sql, $timeout = 60) {
    return Cache::remember(md5($sql), $timeout, function() use ($sql) {
        return DB::raw($sql);
    });
}

$results = $this->cacheQuery("SELECT * FROM stuff INNER JOIN more_stuff");
```

This would cache your queries by creating an MD5 hash of the SQL as the cache key.

Comment: This will not work if using query parameters and unfortunately there's no good way to get the sql with substituted parameters from PDO unless emulating prepared statements.

Answer (score 6):

You can try it like this

```
$stuffTable = Cache::remember('stuffTable', 60, function()
{
 return  DB::table('stuffTable')
          ->select(DB::raw(
             'stuffFields
              A NUMBER OF COMPLEX JOINS, ETC'
          ))->get();
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Of course the cache key shouldn't be the name of the table if you're going to be doing more than one query per table.